# Div tag behaves differently on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, html

I am trying to represent a line inside html. For this I am using this code:

```
<div class="blue_bar" style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>
```

In the CSS I have define this:

```
.blue_bar
{
    height: 5px;
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: rgb(0,0,136);
    margin-top: 10px
}
```

Now, this works good on Google Chrome, but on IE it shows the line different. I have attached two pictures with the results:

Chrome:
[image]

IE:
[image]

Is there a way I can fix the line on IE to look like the one on Chrome ?

edit: This problem occurs when using IE9, it works ok for IE10.

Comment: Use some [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) - [what is a css reset?](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).

Comment: why is background-color in caps ?

Comment: @PatsyIssa; Case does not matter really - see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#CaseSensitivity. This was for SVG but same applies to CSS I understand.

Comment: Don't have IE to check. Can you try adding box-sizing css to DIV. And post a fiddle

Comment: @Exception: can you show me how, I dont usually work with html?

Comment: @vBx Check CSS section in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YfnYm/. This is best practice to maintain cross browser box-model

Comment: @Exception: nothing changed on IE

Answer (score 1):

Add a *font-size: 0;* attribute. Its an IE9 (and lower) bug that doesn't let you have DIV elements smaller than the font size.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.blue_bar
{
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,136);
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="blue_bar" style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

*UPDATE*: Revised this answer to work in IE9

[image: Height fix]

Comment: Do you use IE 10 ? I just tested and it works, but I originally tested on IE 9 and doesn't work

Comment: Yup its an IE9 issue. I changed the compatibility mode from IE10 to IE9 and it displays a broad bar

Comment: Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I don't know why for me it doesn't work. I also cleared the cache

Comment: One last thing - try padding: 0px;

Comment: Must be a problem I can't replicate in compatibility mode. Have attached screenshot to show problem is gone in IE9 compatibility mode.

Comment: I have some last suggestion, which is to run your page through the W3C validator at http://validator.w3.org/ and see if something else is forcing your page to display incorrectly. Also try adding a DOCTYPE declaration to the start of your document. The quick test page I created seems to be running in Quicks mode, so see if you can force it into a proper mode.